# How to set the external monitor as primary screen on my laptop while the screen on my laptop cannot display anything?

Tags: laptop, screen, monitor

My laptop screen is broken and cannot display anything, I'd like to set the monitor as primary display and disable the laptop's screen. Same thing happens on Ubuntu 16.10 and 17

Comment: Please post the output of xrandr (if you can :) )

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fn key + display key (often F4) on your laptop to switch active display.